# How to execute a loop in my method if my variable is initialized to 0?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

My assignment requires me to create a method that reads in data from an input file into a parallel array as well as keep count of how many times the second array receives a value. I've initialized my int n value to 0 but notice that i>0 will not execute since they're both equal. How can I correct this so that the loop is executed.

```
public static int readData (int[] idNumbers, double [] donations)throws Exception {
 
    int n=0;
    
    File myFile = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

    while (inputFile.hasNext())
    { 
      for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
     
     idNumbers[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
     donations[i] = inputFile.nextDouble();
     n++;
                                }

    }
    inputFile.close();
    int donorcount =  n;
    return donorcount;
}
```

Comment: Do you actually need the for loop? Increment `i` at the end of the `while` loop. (Or turn the while loop into `for (; inputFile.hasNext(); ++i)`.

Comment: Right, using both `while` and `for` is not what you want here.  Just use the `while` loop and add one to `n` each time you read a value.